# Trouble with Pyramid Traversal

Tags: python, pyramid, traversal

Clever folks, I need your wisdom. I have an app, which uses URL-Dispatch. Couple of days ago I tried to apply new knowledges about Traversal that I had gotten from tutorials. Of course, it doesn't work :)

I would be very thankful, if you might take a look at this code and say where is my problem. (There is the [link on GitHub](https://github.com/crucl0/gps_tracker/tree/companies/gps_tracker), for convenience)

I'm getting only «404 error», while I'm trying to get response from «/points». And, yes, I'm a newbie not only in «Traversal», but in Pyramid too. As you can see…

**resorces.py:**

```
class Resource(object):
    def __init__(self, request=None, parent=None, name=None):
        self.request = request
        self.__parent__ = parent
        self.__name__ = str(name)


class Root(Resource):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item == 'points':
            return Points(self.request, self, item)
        else:
            raise KeyError('Nope')


class Points(Resource):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item:
            return Point(self.request, self, item)
        else:
            raise KeyError('Nope')


class Point(Resource):
    pass
```

**views.py:**

```
def points_get_all(context, request):
    return context.__name__
```

**__init__.py:**

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from .resources import (Root, Points)
from .views import points_get_all

def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory=Root)
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)

    config.add_view(points_get_all, context=Points, renderer='json')
    config.add_static_view('/', 'gps_tracker:templates/', cache_max_age=0)

    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys from #pyramid IRC (kusut, hello). My mistake is sooo stupid (as it always is) — I put static view at root.

```
config.add_static_view('/', 'gps_tracker:templates/', cache_max_age=0)
```

Be careful, don't repeat my mistake…